# How to render values from object with arrays in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hey everyone I am trying to render a few values inside an object with arrays but have a hard to doing so.
Here is an example of the object:

```
test { 
  arr1: [{alert: "this is alert 1", passed: true}], 
  arr2: [{alert: "this is alert 2", passed: false}], 
  arr3: [{alert: "this is alert 3", passed: true}]
}
```

So basically I want to render the alert and passed values. I tried using Object.keys and then inside mapping individual array based on the key but no luck.

Edit: Sorry if I my question wasn't clear but I was able to resolve it. Here is the code for anyone curious.

```
Object.keys(this.state.test).map((name, I) => (
  this.state.test[name].map((tmp, idx) => (
    <li key={idx}>{tmp.alert}</li>
    <li key={idx}>{tmp.passed}</li>
  ))
))
```

Comment: A code example is worth a thousand words. Your question is not clear. Show your attempt. If nothing else it will give a better idea of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The object is called `Object`, not `Objects`.  Any browser console or build process would be telling you that `Objects` is not defined.

Additionally, you can't have multiple JSX nodes that aren't surrounded by a parent node.  So that's a syntax error in the callback passed to `.map()`.  Which should also be evident as a console error or build error, depending on how you run your application.

Either way, these errors are being reported to you somewhere.  If you're not seeing them then now is a good time to take a step back and better understand your development process, because seeing error messages when things fail is critical.

Once these two things are corrected, your logic works just fine:

```
Object.keys(this.state.test).map((name, I) => (
  this.state.test[name].map((tmp, idx) => (
    <>
      <li key={idx}>{tmp.alert}</li>
      <li key={idx}>{tmp.passed}</li>
    </>
  ))
))
```

Though you may want to re-think your approach a bit, because using the same `key` value for multiple nodes isn't going to make React happy.  It's unlikely to cause any immediate problems, though may produce warnings/errors in the browser console.  But you'd be better off changing the markup a bit to just use a single `<li>` and modify how you're displaying the two values within that element.